# Pesquisa de um valor de uma tabela sem apertar o enter para realizar a pesquisar

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde
Estou enviando um valor para um campo de busca mas ele só envia o valor passado no campo depois que aperto o enter dentro do input, gostaria que ele pesquisasse sem precisar dar o enter só informando o valor.

Segue abaixo o codigo que estou montando.

```
$(document).on('click','.trTable',function(){
    $(this).attr("style","background-color:orange")
        var content1 = $(this).find(':nth-child(3)').text();
        
    $('.input-sm').val(content1);
    document.querySelector('.input-sm').find
    // input-sm e a classe do campo de busca
})
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Penso que você esteja buscando eventos que disparem ao digitar; procura por .keyup(function(); pode ser um caminho...

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas consegui resolver com $('classe').trigger('input'), pois estava pegando o valor de uma coluna e esse valor teria que realizar a pesquisa somente dos valores que estavam nela